# takes or taking, which one of them is correct in my case?

Tags: grammaticality

I have the following sentence:

> Laravel framework gives you something and in return takes something
>   else. It gives you the ease and the simplicity while **takes you** the
>   performance.

Firstly, is the whole sentence grammatically correct as it is now?
Secondly, which one of them is the correct, and why?

- **takes from you**
- **taking from you**
- **takes you**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Takes from you" would be the correct choice as it stands, though that sounds a bit non-idiomatic to me. I think a better way to phrase this might be something like:

> Compared with other PHP frameworks, Laravel offers ease and simplicity of use at the expense of a reduction in performance.

Comment: Thank you. Is your native language is English?